# Solving $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} (\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^2}-\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{(k+1)^2})^2$

Tags: calculus, limits

> Evaluate
>   $$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} (\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^2}-\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{(k+1)^2})^2$$

My attempt :$ (\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^2}-\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{(k+1)^2})
 = \frac{1}{1} -\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^2}-\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}-\frac{1}{4^2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2} = 1- \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$
$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} (1-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2})^2$ =1 
Is this the right way to go ?

Comment: Yes, what you have done is fine.

Comment: Yes, of course!

Comment: Short answer: Yes, this is a telescoping sum!

Comment: Thank you, just wanted to double-check !

Comment: I suggest you write your proof as an answer and accept it, so that the question can be considered solved. [It is fine to answer your own question!]

Comment: Food for thought: 
Can you compute $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^n a_k -\sum_{k=1}^n a_{k+1}?$$